# Publishing a bare-workflow expo React-Native app to Google Play which was previously published in the managed workflow

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

My app was previously built while in the expo managed workflow. I did this using `expo ba`. Because android apps require that you release your app before you can add in-app-purchases, I uploaded this apk and released a beta using it.

I needed to switch to the bare workflow in order to implement in-app-purchases. Now, when trying to create a build to release the actual app, I am following the [React Native instructions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.html) but must create another upload key in order to create a build(which is an aab this time).

On the play console it states

> Upload key: The key you use to sign your first release. Sign every
>   subsequent release with the same key to verify it’s from you. Keep
>   your upload key safe. If it’s ever lost or compromised, contact
>   developer support to replace it.

I'm pretty sure this is a problem because I used whatever expo was giving me to sign the original apk.
I also cannot delete my original app and create a new app with the same bundle name because once an app is released it cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the previously used keystore file run

`expo fetch:android:keystore`

Which will display something like

```
Keystore credentials
  Keystore password: MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
  Key alias:         MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
  Key password:      MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD

  Path to Keystore:  /Path/To/my_upload_store_file.jks
```

Edit the file `android/app/build.gradle` to include the information above

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            //if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file("MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE")
                storePassword "MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD"
                keyAlias "MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS"
                keyPassword "MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD"
            //}
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

Place `my_upload_store_file.jks` inside `android/app`

Edit the file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` or `android/gradle.properties`, and add the following

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE="my_upload_store_file.jks"
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS="MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS"
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD="MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD"
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD="MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD"
```

Run the following in a terminal from the directory `android`

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

This will produce a file called `app-release.aab` inside the directory `android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/`.
Upload this file to the Google Playstore console

Comment: Dude I am in the exact same situation as you but for iOS. Did you have to add your app icon and splash image separately after ejecting? Also did you still use `expo build:android` + `expo upload:android` ?

Comment: I don't think I used `expo upload:android` and I haven't published the iOS version yet

Comment: Yeh looks like I have to build it manually through Xcode. You can still use expo publish for OTA updates though right?

Comment: I don't think I've ever used `expo:publish`  unless that's how you build the apk, I always just dragged my apk onto the console

Comment: @bigpotato I'm really not an expert, thankfully I wrote down how to do this in the answer here so I'll know how to do it next time